# JavaScript to click on a div inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I want to click on a particular div inside the iframe using JavaScript. Is it possible?

Something like

```
<iframe src="http://www.gumtree.com.au"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
function fun1(){
   document.getElementbyId("#mygumtree").click();
}
</script>
```

This didn't work. Is there any code that can do this process? Thanks.

Comment: You don't have access to cross-domain (i)frames.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: That would be the __worst__ security hole.

Comment: it wont work because you are not calling the function

Comment: Notice that you have to use **.onclick()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the code for this somewhere
**But it is not possible** to access content of iFrame.